# Ubuntu with LAMP+Mediawiki suffering spikes

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm sorry if this question is off topic, but I'll give it a shot:

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04, a LAMP stack, and Mediawiki. After installing Mediawiki I noticed that my wiki site was spiking, i.e. every couple of pages loads would take much longer than necessary.

I connected to the server through SSH to find the same problem: I manage to type 4-5 characters perfectly well, but then it takes around 10 seconds to revive and continue reading my keyboard input.

I ran the `top` command and I see `mysql` jumping to the top of the list every 5 seconds, taking up apx. 20-40% of CPU.

The VPS has 20 GB of SSD, 512 Mb of main memory.

Is there an obvious fix to this?

p.s. If this is off topic here, would anyone point me to an appropriate site to ask this question?

Comment: Since you've already narrowed it down to `mysql` you might [check out the currently active queries](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-running-queries-mysql/) and if it's an issue with the sheer volume of a particular set of queries you may tool with mysql query caching settings.